# DDD: Относятся ли к домену категории, теги или лайки агрегата?

Tags: php, ddd

Если посмотреть с одной стороны, эти элементы просто помогают пользователю взаимодействовать с интерфейсом (фильтровать в случае категорий или тегов, выражать мнение в случае лайков) с агрегатами, а не изменять их состояние? То есть логически это все относится к слою приложения (или вообще UI) и может быть помещено в отдельные его сервисы, никак не пересекающиеся с доменом?
А если с другой - агрегат (допустим статья) может иметь только одну категорию, или лайк определенному сообщению на форуме пользователь может поставить только один раз - а это уже бизнес-логика и должна разрешаться в самом агрегате, доменном сервисе или команде.
Помогите разобраться)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю это зависит от того, что и как вы моделируете и надо начать с usecase сценариев. В любом случае, лайк или категория это не понятие уровня приложение, а скорее уровня модели. Взять статьи и категории. Скорее всего вам придется их сделать двумя отдельными агрегатами - Category and Article. Хотя бы потому, что придется работать как отдельно со статьей, так и со списком статей в категории.

```
Article
    ID
    Title
    CategoryID

Category
    ID
    Name
```

Usecase

- GetArticleById(articleID)
- GetListOfCategories()
- GetArticlesInCategory(categoryID)